# Hash and function parameters in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to write something like that :

```
class Test
  def initialize(a,b,c)
  end

  def print()
    puts @a
    puts @b
    puts @c
  end
end

Test.new({a=>1, b=>2, c=>3}).print()
=>1
=>2
=>3
```

Is there a way to instanciate an object and map its parameters with an hash table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, use Ruby 2 and named parameters. Otherwise, no, just extract the options from the hash and assign them to your variables.

Comment: @meagar Could you give me some ressources with good examples please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Test
  def initialize(options)
    options.each do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
    end
  end

  def print
    puts @a
    puts @b
    puts @c
  end
end

Test.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3).print
```

Or use `OpenStruct`:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html

Here's a simple example:

```
require 'ostruct'

puts OpenStruct.new(:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3).inspect
# Outputs: "#<OpenStruct a=1, b=2, c=3>"
```

Comment: Yes, ok, but you did the mapping yourself

Comment: @Pol0nium There is no built-in mechanism for this in Ruby < 2.0. In Ruby 1.9.3 you *have* to do the mapping yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your examples. Could you show me how to do this properly in Ruby 2.0 please?

Answer (score 4):

If you still are using Ruby 1.9.3 you can use a Hash object pretty easily:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c

  def initialize(h)
     h.each {|k,v| send("#{k}=",v)}
  end

  def print()
    puts @a
    puts @b
    puts @c
  end
end

Test.new( {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}).print()
# 1
# 2
# 3
# => nil
```

Keep in mind however that it will create a variable called whatever you pass as the key, if that doesn't match `a`,`b`, or `c` your accessors will fail.

Comment: Thanks for your example. But I really want to be sure that the Hash matches the names that I wrote in initialize.
And I'm not forced to use Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 3):

In a *current* version of Ruby, you can use keyword arguments:

```
def initialize(a: nil, b: nil, c: nil)
  @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
end
```

Note that currently, keyword parameters always have a default value and are thus always optional. If you want to make keyword arguments mandatory, you can use the simple trick that the default value can be *any* Ruby expression:

```
def mand(name) raise ArgumentError, "#{name} is mandatory!" end

def initialize(a: mand 'a', b: mand 'b', c: mand 'c')
  @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
end
```

In the next version of Ruby it is possible to have mandatory keyword arguments by just omitting the default value:

```
def initialize(a:, b:, c:)
  @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
end
```

See here:

```
class Test
  def initialize(a:, b:, c:)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end

  def to_s
    instance_variables.map {|v| "#{v} = #{instance_variable_get(v)}" }.join("\n")
  end
end

puts Test.new(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
# @a = 1
# @b = 2
# @c = 3
```

Comment: What does 'In a *current* version of Ruby' mean?

Comment: Ruby 2.0.0-p0 or later. Mandatory keyword arguments work in a recent snapshot of Ruby 2.1.0. (Actually, it doesn't even have to be *that* recent, mine is several months old but it already has them.)